# Window A/C Dimensions

Tags: air-conditioning

I measured my window width: 19.5"
I measured my old A/C (5,000 BTU): 18"

I used that A/C for a few years and it was great. But I figured I'll get a new one. Maybe more powerful.

But suddenly, every A/C I look at... I can't tell if it would fit or not because of phrasing possibly.

Look at this [Haier Esa406n-T 6000 Btu Window Air Conditioner](http://www.factorydirect.ca/Canada-Ontario-/Home___Garden/Environmental/Home___Garden_Environmental_Air_Conditioners/HA4060/ESA406N-T_HAIER_ESA406N-T_6000_BTU_WINDOW_AIR_CONDITIONER_/0)

- Dimensions: 18.5" W x 14" D x 12.4375" H.
- Depth Including Front: 15.34375"
- Window Width: Min. - 24.5" ; Max. - 36"
- Window Height Min.: 13.375"

Based on that, I can't tell whether it will fit in my window, because the unit width is 18.5" (And the box visually looks like it should fit. And there is probably Styrofoam padding inside too.
Or will it not fit? What does it mean by minimum window width being 24.5" ??

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra 4" on the window width requirement is from the expanding side panels, which, while expandable/collapsible, are likely a minimum of 2" wide each. If you're creative, you could use other means to close off the gap on either side of the unit (though with just a half inch on each side, you may not need to). I would check the return policy of wherever you choose to buy, though, in case it doesn't quite fit.